# Unable to fire LinkButton_Click Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, onclick, dynamic-controls

Actually,I'm `Dynamically generating Controls` and adding them to a `Panel`.
Now,I'm showing my `Records` `Count` in a `LinkButton` and on `LinkButton_Click`,I'm showing the actual Records.
On the `Page_Load`,the data is Binding Perfect and all the controls gets added to the `Panel`.
But after clicking the `LinkButton`,It is not entering the `LinkButton_Click` event.
I'm getting an error after the `Page_Load` event like :

> **The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
>   among the padding characters.**

It doesn't even enter into `Catch Block`.

My `LinkButton` code :

```
LinkButton lblCount = new LinkButton() { ID = "lblCount" + j + i + 1, Text = ans_count.ToString() };
//lblCount.EnableDefaultAppearance = false;
lblCount.EnableTheming = false;
lblCount.ForeColor = Color.Black;
lblCount.Font.Bold = true;
lblCount.Font.Underline = true;

string strval = String.Format("{0}~{1}~{2}", tempid, questionid, answerid);
lblCount.CommandArgument = strval;
lblCount.Click += new EventHandler(this.LbtnCount_Click);
Panel_Answers.Controls.Add(lblCount);
```

Comment: how you append the event to your dynamic controls?

Comment: I have updated my question with my LinkButton Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to add your controls in OnInit Event not page load, give it a try